Firebase Cloud Functions writing on firestore database doesn't affect firestore emulator
I just got started with Firebase Cloud Functions. I'm just trying to update a document field on my Firestore Database through an https triggered function.
Here is my code:
import * as v2 from "firebase-functions/v2";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {Request, Response} from "express";
admin.initializeApp();

export const helloworld = v2.https
  .onRequest(async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    if (request.method === "GET") {
      const firstName = request.query.firstName;
      if (!firstName) {
        response
          .status(400)
          .send("\"firstName\" missing in query string.");
      }

      const db = admin.firestore();
      try {
        await db.collection("users").doc("***@gmail.com").update({
          firstName: firstName,
        });
        response
          .status(200)
          .send("\"firstName\" field correctly updated.");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during updating field:", error);
        response
          .status(500)
          .send("Error during field update.");
      }
    } else {
      response
        .status(405)
        .send("This function only accept GET method.");
    }
  });


I run this with npm run serve on my terminal, which should launch npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions, and everything works fine on the online Firestore Database. The problem is that my document on the Emulator doesn't get affected by the function. What am I doing wrong?
